# Flutter - Regex in TextFormField

Tags: regex, flutter

I´m trying to only allow numbers and points on a text form field.

I have something like that

```
WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("\d*[.]\d*"))
```

But does not work, so: Anybody have idea how can only allow digits and point?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since [`WhitelistingTextInputFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/WhitelistingTextInputFormatter-class.html) is deprecated in Flutter as of 1.20, [`FilteringTextInputFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html) can be used:

> A [TextInputFormatter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html) that prevents the insertion of characters
> matching (or not matching) a particular pattern.
>
> Instances of filtered characters found in the new [TextEditingValue](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextEditingValue-class.html)s
> will be replaced with the [replacementString](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter/replacementString.html) which defaults to the
> empty string.
>
> Since this formatter only removes characters from the text, it
> attempts to preserve the existing [TextEditingValue.selection](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextEditingValue/selection.html) to values
> it would now fall at with the removed characters.

Example use:

```
TextField(
 keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$')),
  ], 
),
```

**Legacy answer**

[`WhitelistingTextInputFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/WhitelistingTextInputFormatter/WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.html) *"creates a formatter that allows only the insertion of whitelisted characters patterns"*. It means your pattern should just match any 1 digit  or 1 dot.

Also, you need to use a raw string literal if you want to use a single backslash with regex escapes.

Use

```
WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r"[\d.]"))
```

Note that if you want to validate the whole input *sequence* you need to define a `validator: validateMyInput` and then add

```
String validateMyInput(String value) {
    Pattern pattern = r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
      return 'Enter Valid Number';
    else
      return null;
  }
```

Adapted from [*Form Validation in Flutter*](https://medium.com/@nitishk72/form-validation-in-flutter-d762fbc9212c).

Comment: WhitelistingTextInputFormatter is deprecated, you should use FilteringTextInputFormatter (FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow for WhitelistingTextInputFormatter replacement )

Comment: The answer seems incorrect: `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow` accepts a regexp for a single character, not an expression for the entire input like `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`.