# How to allow numbers and digits but only one comma in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to allow only one comma to be added to my `inputNumber` in flutter, I can't find any solution for this, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Would love to help, but what exactly do you need? Its not very clear...
Do you want to allow only one decimal character after the comma (like 5.4 and not 5.46)?

Comment: I need to block the insertion of more than one comma so that doesn't happen (2,,,30)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390839/flutter-regex-in-textformfield

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Regex in TextFormField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390839/flutter-regex-in-textformfield)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I found was to check the digit entered, if it already exists (",") I block it

```
       if ((newChar.contains(",") || newChar.contains(".")) && (oldValue.text.contains(","))) {
      return TextEditingValue(
        text: oldValue.text,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: oldValue.text.length),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can White list some text using this:-- 
`WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"))`

You can Black list some text using this:-- 
`BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[/\\]"))`

Comment: I need to block the insertion of more than one comma so that doesn't happen (2,,,30)