# Regular expressions limit occurence for optional

Tags: regex

I want to allow any letters or digits and if used, allow `#` only at the beginning with only one occurence something like `#{1}`. And keep those restrictions that I already have in the expression for characters `^<>@.\/()`.

Here is my Regex:

```
/^[#?a-zA-z0-9][^<>@.\/()]+/g
```

Some use cases I want this regex expression to pass:

```
##msidfipds - fail (2 of #)
fdsfsdfd#1m - fail (# not 1st character)
vcvxcvxcvxc - pass
#fdfdsfsdfs - pass
```

Use case for `TextField` widget.

```
TextField(
    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
           FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^#?[a-zA-Z0-9][^#<>@.\/()]*$')),
   ],
   autofocus: true,
   enableInteractiveSelection: true,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
       fillColor: Colors.transparent,
       border: InputBorder.none,
       hintText: 'Search',
   ),
   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
   style: TextFieldStyle,
),
```

Comment: You likely have a typo in your first character class, it should read: `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Comment: [`^#?[^#<>@.\/()]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/DjD39T/1)

Comment: Aha, so this is Dart.

Answer (score 1):

Use a beginning anchor, and then an optional quantifier:

```
/^#?[a-zA-Z0-9][^<>@.\/()]+/g
```

This will ensure that if an octothorpe occurs, it must occur at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
^#?[a-zA-Z0-9][^#<>@.\/()]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HFTDX5/1).

**NOTE**: [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926), you need `[A-Za-z]` to only match letters.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `#?` - an optional `#` char
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an alphanumeric char
- `[^#<>@.\/()]+` - one or more chars other than `#`, `<`, `>`, `@`, `.`, `/`, `(` and `)`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Hey @Wiktor, thank you for your answer but I have not yet been able to find a solution. I needed that Regex in order to restrict user input. I have found the following asnwer to question that I want to use for my TextField.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390839/flutter-regex-in-textformfield
I have updated my question, and right now my TextField is blocked and cannot type anything there.

Comment: @user12051965  Maybe because even one single char input should be matched with the regex. Try `^#?[a-zA-Z0-9][^#<>@.\/()]*$`

Comment: I tried exactly this and cannot type '#' at the beginning, only letters and digits, and when I write # somewhere in the middle it deletes everything in input.